# SeekBar on Mono for Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, seekbar

I would like to create a seekbar for a Mono for Android app that allows the user to select and i want to implement the SeekBar Widget, how can i use a SeekBarChangeListener() on Mono for Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write a change listener you need a class that implements `SeekBar.IOnSeekBarChangeListener`:

```
public class SeekBarListener : Java.Lang.Object, SeekBar.IOnSeekBarChangeListener
{
    public void OnProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, bool fromUser)
    {
    }

    public void OnStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
    {
    }

    public void OnStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
    {
    }
}
```

Then you can assign that to the seek bar:

```
seekBar.SetOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBarListener());
```

Comment: thanks but it throws me an error when i want to do this txtCache.SetText(progress,Button.BufferType.Normal); inherit from another activity cuz im creating this seekbar in a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Well i resolve this in the same class implementing SeekBar.IOnSeekBarChangeListener on another way here is my code:

```
private void CreateDialogSeek()
    {

        dialogSeek = new Dialog(this);
        dialogSeek.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.seekbar_dialog);
        dialogSeek.SetTitle("Change your configuration"); 
        dialogSeek.SetCancelable(true);
          //Ok
          btnOk = (Button)(dialogSeek.FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnSettingsOKSeekBar));
          btnCancel = (Button)(dialogSeek.FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnSettingsCancelSeekBar));
          SeekBar mSeekBar = (SeekBar)(dialogSeek.FindViewById(Resource.Id.seekbar));
          mSeekBar.Progress = cache;
          mSeekBar.SetOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

        dialogSeek.Show();
        btnOk.Click += delegate {OKSeek();};
        btnCancel.Click += delegate {dialogSeek.Dismiss();;};
    }

    public void OnProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, bool fromUser)
    {
        cache = progress;
    }

    public void OnStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
    {
    }

    public void OnStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
    {
    }
```

Comment: and on the OKSeek() method i can put this code that was trowing me an error....txtCache.SetText(cache.ToString(), Button.BufferType.Normal);